# Vídeo não listado no youtube problemas para abrir usando iframe

Tags: html, html5

Não estou conseguindo abrir vídeos não listados no youtube usando a tag html `iframe`, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Alguém sabe o que é? Tentei usando a tag video e também não está funcionando.

```
   <iframe width="420" height="315"
                            src="videodoyoutubenaolistado"></iframe>
```

Comment: Resolvi o problema o erro bem bobo, entrei no link do youtube e usando o botão de incorporar ele me gerou o código html alterando a url no formato que funciona.

Answer (score 2):

muitos sites famosos acabam bloqueando a incorporação em iframes por conta de que isso permite a criação de sites maliciosos, então sempre que pensar em usar iframe pra um site ve se ele próprio não oferece opção de incorporação de partes especificas.

No caso do youtube para evitar erros assim pois ele não permite a página toda e para ter q evitar de ir pegar a incorporação no site você pode mudar a url substituindo watch?v= por embed/ isso já faz com que seja pego somente a janela do vídeo.

Exemplo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw => https://www.youtube.com/embed/T-TwcmT6Rcw

pode ver outras funções aqui https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_youtube.asp